# SOAP UI Groovy Script returns exception: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException (-2) I do not get it why

Tags: php, soap, groovy

I am working currently with SoapUI, i am a bit of a noob at it I am trying with a script to retrieve a Set-Cookie PHP Session ID from the HTTP Header however i get the exception above. Regardless here is my script code:

```
def header = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Authenticate").httpRequest.response.responseHeaders["Set-Cookie"]
header = header.toString()
start = header.indexOf("PHPSESSID=")
end = header.indexOf("; Path=")
sessionIdValue= header.substring(start, end)
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("FavouriteLocations").setPropertyValue("session_key",sessionIdValue)
```

I would appreciate any input you may have.

Comment: What content do you have one header variable? I suspect that in the header there isn't "PHPSESSID=" or "; Path=". There is why you are getting StringindexOutOfBoundsException on header.substring(start,end). Print the header content with log.info header on your groovy script.

Comment: Try this: http://siking.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/soapui-cookie-management/ HTH.

Comment: It worked in the end, sorry for the late reply. Thanks for trying!